How to make a function that prints progress indicator when used in Map[], even if called in pure form?
How can I make a function that will print a progress indicator whenever its mapped over list, even if called in pure form?
It seems clear that what I want is an upvalue Creating an upvalue for f regarding Map is straightforward, and I can implement my  progress indicator and it works for expressions of the form f/@{1,2,3} but not those of the form f[#]&/@{1,2,3}.
ClearAll[addMapProgress, f]
addMapProgress[f_Symbol, OptionsPattern[]] := (
  f /: Map[f, list_] := DynamicModule[{iter, temp, out},
     iter = 0;
     PrintTemporary[ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[iter/Length[list]]]];
     out = Map[(++iter; f[#]) &, list];
     out];
  )
f[x_] := (Pause[0.3]; x)
addMapProgress[f]
f /@ Range[3] (*prints progress*)
f[#] & /@ Range[3](*doesn't print progress*)

But I would like to also see progress when using the function in a pure function. The issue is that the upvalue doesn't match in the pure function case because the head of the thing inside Map is Function, and not f.

FWIW, there are two resource functions (that I know of) that track progress: “MonitorProgress” and “DynamicMap”.

Also, it might be simpler to implement this with Table + Monitor (if you don’t actually need the progress bar) or Table + ProgressIndicator.

well... wish I had known that earlier. Wait those don't let me use /@ (do they?) which is kinda a deal breaker for me

The resource functions work with Map. My suggestion to use Table was a modification/simplification of your implementation.

I don't understand, how would I use those resource functions to make f[#]&/@list work as I desire? wouldn't I have to use ResourceFunction["DynamicMap"][f[#] &, list] in the case of "DynamicMap"? I'm requiring that this exact syntax work: f[#]&/@list

ResourceFunction["MonitorProgress"] seems to be fine?: f[x_, y_] := (Pause[0.5]; x^2);  ResourceFunction["MonitorProgress"][f[#, 10] & /@ {1, 2, 3}] If one wants DynamicMap, a possible solution is: help = Function[expr, Unevaluated@expr /. Map -> ResourceFunction["DynamicMap"], HoldAll]; f[#, 10] & /@ {1, 2, 3} // help

@xzczd congratulations on being elected moderator! (I voted for you and as such demand special treatment).

Thanks for your support! (But politics is an ungrateful business dude https://i.sstatic.net/bmO3peNU.png )

I'm not sure this qualifies as an answer, but it might possibly be helpful to others later.
Given a function f and some expression involving mapping f over a list, we want a progress indicator relative to the length of the list. Several strategies are available, including

update the definition of f itself, presumably with UpValues
define a new version of Map that adds the progress indicator
explore existing functions (built-in and in resource repository) whose purpose is to show progress

Personally, I recommend against #1. It involves polluting the definition of f with non-functional concerns (i.e. concerns related not to the semantics of f but instead to the semantics of Map). Complecting these concerns will make maintenance  and extension more difficult (which admittedly may not be a concern for OP).  We also need to duplicate the process with any other function we want to augment in the future. The addMapProgress utility is a clever way to mitigate some of that risk, but the generality to complexity ratio is still pretty low. That's just my assessment, YMMV. Anyway, I would discourage anyone from attempting that strategy, so I'll focus on the others.
Let's try to roll our own bespoke function. It could be something like this:
MapWithProgress[f_,list_,etc___]:=
  Module[
    {progressIterator=0,length=Length[list]},
    PrintTemporary[ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[progressIterator/length]]];
    MapIndexed[(progressIterator=#2[[1]];f[#1])&,list,etc]]

To see it work, try these:
MapWithProgress[Pause[.2] &, Range[10]];
MapWithProgress[f,RandomInteger[{1,9},{5,5}],{2}];
MapWithProgress[Pause[.2] &, hello["a", "b", "c"]];
MapWithProgress[f, Range[100000]];

I haven't placed restrictions on the arguments, but of course you could. My thinking was that I'm just passing to MapIndexed anyway, so I'll just get default behavior for "weird" inputs which seems better than trying to introduce unnecessary error handling. As for using MapIndexed, that was just an easy way to expose an iterator to ProgressIndicator; this function could have been implemented other ways.
In the comments, OP mentioned wanting the exact syntax of f[#] & /@ Range[3]. If the desire is to keep using Map, then one could employ Block:
Block[
  {Map = MapWithProgress},
  f[#] & /@ Range[3]]

If the desire is for infix form, then
f[#] &~MapWithProgress~Range[3]

One could define one's own infix operator to make that cleaner. If the problem is that we have pre-existing code that we cannot edit (neither f's definition nor its usages), then we may need to fall back to UpValues:
f/:Map[f,args__]:=MapWithProgress[f,args]

Now we turn to pre-existing functions for monitoring progress. We have Monitor, but we need to feed it a symbol to track. We could use the same basic strategy in MapWithProgress--I won't duplicate that implementation. So let's turn to the function repository. We have "DynamicMap":
ResourceFunction["DynamicMap"][Pause[.2]&,Range[10]

We have "MonitorProgress":
ResourceFunction["MonitorProgress"][Map[Pause[.2]&,Range[10]]]

The visualizations here are more complex that just a simple progress indicator, but one could edit the source code to get fine-grain control. The advantages here are (1) we don't need to implement anything ourselves, and (2) we have vetted functions that are (presumably) robust, reliable, introduce minimal overhead, and are much more general. We can use Block or UpValues as previously demonstrated if absolutely necessary.

nice answer, very complementary to mine in ways I think are absolutely useful to point out. I am using this to modify certain expensive functions (like a custom fitting routine) so messing with the functions definitions such is something I'm quite comfortable with, but as you point out it lacks the robustness of (presumably) robust vetted functions. Also 'generality to complexity ratio' is a phrase I'm going to use a lot now. :)

ha! glad you think it might be useful even though it doesn't directly address your question about pure-function-form.

The following code extends addMapProgress to dynamically generate a version of f inside a pure function and attach the same upvalue to it.
The key idea is to redefine Function[f[x_]] to create a temporary version of f with progress-tracking logic applied. This version also works if it has options or if multiple arguments, with a single slot. I don't think it works in its present form if you are trying to use multiple slots or slot sequence. The slot may have to be the first argument in the present implementation
ClearAll[addMapProgress, f]
Options[addMapProgress] = {optionIncludePureDefinition -> True};
addMapProgress[f_Symbol, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 (
  f /: Map[f, list_] := Module[{iter, temp, out},
        iter = 0;
        Print[ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[iter/Length[list]]]];
        out = Map[(++iter; f[#]) &, list];
    out];
  
  If[OptionValue[optionIncludePureDefinition],
    f /: Function[f[x_, y___, opts : OptionsPattern[]]] := 
    Module[{temp2, out2},
            temp2[xx_] := f[xx, y, opts];
            out2 = temp2;
            addMapProgress[temp2, optionIncludePureDefinition -> False];
        out2]
   ];
  )


(*pretty sure all these works as desired*)
f[x_, y_] := (Pause[0.3]; x^2 - y)
addMapProgress[f]
f[#, 10] & /@ {1, 2, 3}


Options[g] = {optionTest -> "default"};
g[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := (Print["Option: ", OptionValue[optionTest]];
   Pause[0.3]; x);
addMapProgress[g];
g /@ Range[3]                     
g[#] & /@ Range[3]                
g[#, optionTest -> "not default"] & /@ Range[3]  

Options[h] = {optionTest -> "default"};
h[x_, y_, OptionsPattern[]] := (Print[OptionValue[optionTest]]; 
  Pause[0.3]; x^2 - y)
addMapProgress[h]
h[#, 10] & /@ Range[3]
h[#, 10, optionTest -> "not default"] & /@ Range[3]

